# Some HTML elements are not showing when displayed using an ngIf?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I have two buttons with varying routerlinks. Each should appear differently based on the outcome of an ngIf. However, what happens is that on loading the page for the first time, neither of these buttons load until the page is refreshed (despite having loading for the page - to wait for the data to load):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="moduleList">

...

     <button *ngIf="!item.TrainingModuleCompleted" mat-stroked-button [routerLink]="['training-modules-content-view', item.TrainingModuleId]" class="module-view">Select</button>
     <button *ngIf="item.TrainingModuleCompleted" mat-stroked-button [routerLink]="['training-modules-content-view', item.TrainingModuleId]" class="module-view">View</button>

...

</ng-container>
```

As can be seen above, a different button will be shown depending on whether `item.TrainingModuleCompleted` is true or not. This variable is loaded with `moduleList`.

This is the buttons before being loaded in (on initial load):

[image]

This is the buttons after being loaded (after refreshing the page):

[image]

The ngIf is obviously being hit before the data is loaded in.. Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: You can use class and show hide in css for this. So your element will be there

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that if you looked in the console you would see an error during the initial load. Is it possible that `item` is null or undefined when the page loads? If so, you should add a null check on item like this.

`*ngIf="item?.TrainingModuleCompleted"`

Also, if all you swapping out is the button text, I would just do that rather than have two buttons...
`{{ item?.TrainingModuleCompleted ? 'View' : 'Select' }}`

Answer (score 0):

If you load your datas after a "subscribe", you can do sth like this:

```
dataWS.subscribe(
    (data) => {
       //Called when success
     },
    (error) => {
       //Called when error
    }
  ).add(() => {
       //load the variable you want after
  });
```